# SQL function not displaying two decimal places although input parameter value is float

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, floating-point

I have a function that rounds to the nearest value in SQL as per below. When I pass my value in and run the function manually, it works as expected. However when I use it within a `select` statement, it removes the decimal places.

E.g. I expect the output to be 9.00 but instead I only see 9.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_PriceLadderCheck]
    (@CheckPrice FLOAT,
     @Jur VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReturnPrice FLOAT

    IF (@Jur = 'SE')
    BEGIN
        SET @ReturnPrice = (SELECT [Swedish Krona ]
                            FROM tbl_priceladder_swedishkrona
                            WHERE [Swedish Krona ] = @CheckPrice +
                                                     (SELECT MIN(ABS([Swedish Krona ] - @CheckPrice))
                                                      FROM tbl_priceladder_swedishkrona)
                               OR [Swedish Krona ] = @CheckPrice -
                                                     (SELECT MIN(ABS([Swedish Krona ] - @CheckPrice))
                                                      FROM tbl_priceladder_swedishkrona))
    END

    IF (@Jur = 'DK')
    BEGIN
        SET @ReturnPrice = (SELECT [Danish Krone ]
                            FROM tbl_priceladder_danishkrone
                            WHERE [Danish Krone ] = @CheckPrice +
                                                    (SELECT MIN(ABS([Danish Krone ] - @CheckPrice))
                                                     FROM tbl_priceladder_danishkrone)
                               OR [Danish Krone ] = @CheckPrice -
                                                    (SELECT MIN(ABS([Danish Krone ] - @CheckPrice))
                                                     FROM tbl_priceladder_danishkrone))
        END

    RETURN @ReturnPrice 
END
```

Run SQL manually:

```
 declare @checkprice float
set @checkprice = '10.3615384615385'

SELECT [Swedish Krona ]
FROM tbl_priceladder_swedishkrona
WHERE [Swedish Krona ] = @CheckPrice +
      ( SELECT MIN(ABS([Swedish Krona ] - @CheckPrice))
        FROM tbl_priceladder_swedishkrona
      )
   OR [Swedish Krona ] = @CheckPrice -
      ( SELECT MIN(ABS([Swedish Krona ] - @CheckPrice))
        FROM tbl_priceladder_swedishkrona
      )
```

When I use this function with a SQL select statement for some reason it removes the 2 decimal points.

```
SELECT 
    Article, Colour, 
    dbo.fn_PriceLadderCheck([New Price], 'se') AS [New Price]
FROM 
    #temp2 t
```

[New Price] on its own is example output is 10.3615384615385

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try an example where the expected result is 9.xx.

Comment: What is the definition of `[New Price]` in `#temp2`?

Comment: Isn't it normal that a float is displayed like that?  What does this show you : `select cast(9.00 as decimal(16,2)), cast(9.00 as float)`.  Floats are only approximately accurate btw.  Not really intended for [money](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql)

Comment: @ChrisCatignani - this input I expect the output to be 9.00. But it comes back as 9

Comment: Let me try decimal then

Comment: If it isn't too late I would suggest using a single table here instead of two. You would need to add another column for currency. Your system will be way more flexible and simpler to use. If you add a new currency you don't need to change anything, just add rows with the new currency. And then this type of query becomes painless as you just use a where clause instead of if conditions and multiple queries hitting different tables.

Comment: @LukStorms this fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the result into a Decimal and specify the scale. 
See the example below.

```
RETURN SELECT CAST(@ReturnPrice AS DECIMAL(16,2))
```